# Why is there a limit in accessing array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, limit

The OSX system can allocate the memory just fine from malloc (return non-NULL).  However when accessing position pass 1073741823, Segmentation fault: 11 happened.  Can anyone please educate me the reason?

I can access any points below 1073741824 just fine (as shown in the code.) I did try accessing random positions above 1073741824 point and results were still the same error while any random access below 1073741824 worked just fine.

```
    void dead(){
        size_t pos = 0;
        size_t max =2147483647;
        max *= 2;
        printf("%ld\n",max);
        int* data = malloc(max);
        if(data == NULL){exit(1);}
        pos = 2147483647/2;
        pos-=3;
        for (; pos < 2147483647; pos++) {
            printf("%ld\n",pos);
            data[pos] = 10;
            printf("%i\n",data[pos]);
        }
    }

    4294967294
    1073741820
    10
    1073741821
    10
    1073741822
    10
    1073741823
    10
    1073741824
    Segmentation fault: 11
```

Theoretically it should not die there.

Comment: I think some implementations of `malloc` have an undocumented behavior on certain inputs like `(size_t)-2`, and do something other than actually allocate memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `malloc()` function allocates `chars`, and `sizeof(int)` is typically much larger than 1 char.

For example; if you allocate memory for 2147483647 chars but a `sizeof(int)` is "4 chars"; then you've only allocated enough memory for "2147483647/4 = 536870911 ints".

Note that `malloc()` typically asks the operating system for a larger amount of memory and splits it up into smaller pieces. This means that when you access something you didn't allocate with `malloc()` you may still access the larger amount of memory that `malloc()` asked the OS for, so you don't get a page fault ("segmentation fault") as soon as you access something you didn't allocate (more specifically, you don't get "segmentation fault" as soon as you try to access the 536870912th `int` that you didn't allocate memory for).